# How to deal with go RPC calling with an array as its return value?

Tags: go, rpc

I want to export my service as an RPC service and my local method is to get all users(struct type) from db such as follows,

```
func GetUsers() ([]model.User) {
    // business logic
}
```

Now I wrapped the method as the RPC patterns as follows,

```
func (api *API) RpcGetUsers(_, reply []*model.User) error {
    reply = dal.GetUsers()
    return nil
}
```

But When I ran the function an panic occurred. It mentioned that

> "reply type of method "RpcGetUsers" is not a pointer: "[]*model.User""

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPC documentation says the method must look like:

```
func (t *T) MethodName(argType T1, replyType *T2) error
```

So you need a request and a reply type. You can do something like this:

```
type Empty struct{}
type Users struct {
   Users []model.User
}

func (api *API) RpcGetUsers(_ *Empty, reply *Users) error {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion I will try it